# Fullcalendar not loading properly first time(vue js)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm using `@fullcalendar/vue`. My calendar is not loading properly for the first time. When I change month or view then it displayed properly.

This is my config

```
calendarOptions: {
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, timeGridPlugin ],
    contentHeight: 1000,
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
    eventClick: this.eventClick,
    eventMouseEnter: this.eventMouseover,
    eventMouseLeave: this.eventMouseout,
    events: [],
    selectable: true,
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today Appointment',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' 
    },
```

}

Events are pushed to `events[]` dynamically on created hook.
Please guide me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously we can't see the code for populating the events, but I would assume that `events` is not being populated until *after* the calendar has rendered, presumably because the code which populates it is asynchronous. When the calendar first renders you are clearly giving it an empty array, so that's what you'll see until something changes and the calendar re-renders.

Instead of having an entirely separate event populating process, try using fullCalendar's built-in events feed functionality - either directly using a [JSON feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) where you give fullCalendar the URL to fetch the data from the server, or indirectly using a [callback function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) which fullCalendar can call whenever it needs to fetch events. This option is a bit more flexible, especially if you have a server-side API where you can't change it to supply JSON in the exact format fullCalendar requires, or if you need to also have code to put the event data into other variables for use elsewhere in your front-end application. Those documentation links have more information on exactly how each option works.

Both of these approaches also enable you to have a situation where you only download the events fullcalendar actually *needs* - because you would make sure use the start and end dates fullCalendar supplies to you each time to filter the list of returned events to just the range which is going to be displayed in the current view. fullCalendar will automatically request more events if/when the user changes the date range. This is generally more efficient, especially after a longer period where you have probably got a big list of past events in your database, and you don't want to be downloading all of them every time, when no-one is likely to look at them.